Trouble with HC-SR04 sensor
I am working with the PIC24Fj64GA002 microcontroller operating at 16MHz and the HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor. I believe my hardware is operating correctly. I used a logic analyzer to confirm that the sensor was sending signals back to my microcontroller, and when putting a breakpoint in my input capture ISR, the program correctly stops inside of it. This tells me the issue is with my code.
I am having an issue debugging this code. I placed an object in front of the sensor and varied its distance from the sensor. However, when placing a breakpoint inside the else statement in my input capture ISR, the distance value I am getting is not expected, and on top of that the distance won't change as I move the object.
One debugging step I took was connect my RB4 and RB5 pins together, and knowing that I am sending a pulse of 10us from RB5, I tested to see if the finalVal would correspond to 10us. It did not, so this tells me the formula I am using in my program is wrong.
What steps should I take from here?
#include "xc.h"
#include <stdbool.h>

bool stopMotion = 0;
volatile uint32_t finalTime = 0;
volatile int overflowtmr = 0;
int distanceThreshold = 1;

void setup(){
    CLKDIVbits.RCDIV = 0;
    TRISBbits.TRISB4 = 1;  //input for echo
    TRISBbits.TRISB5 = 0; //output for trig 
    LATBbits.LATB5 = 0;

    //IC1 setup
    IC1CONbits.ICTMR = 0; //timer 3
    IC1CONbits.ICM = 1;

    //PPS for IC1
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON & 0xbf);// unlock PPS
    RPINR7bits.IC1R = 4;  // RP4 (pin 11)
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | 0x40); // lock   PPS

    T3CON = 0;
    TMR3 = 0;
    T3CONbits.TCKPS = 0;
    _T3IF = 0; //a prescaler of 1 for TMR3
    PR3 = 65535;
    T3CONbits.TON = 1;

    IFS0bits.T3IF = 0;
    IEC0bits.T3IE = 1;
    IPC2bits.T3IP = 3;
    IFS0bits.IC1IF = 0;
    IEC0bits.IC1IE = 1;
    IPC0bits.IC1IP = 3;

    //TIMER1 setup
    T1CON = 0;
    TMR1 = 0;
    T1CONbits.TCKPS = 0;
    _T1IF = 0;
    PR1 = 160; //for a delay of 10uS
    T1CONbits.TON = 0;

    IFS0bits.T1IF = 0;
    IEC0bits.T1IE = 1;
    IPC0bits.T1IP = 5; //higher priority than the input capture interrupt

}

void __attribute__((interrupt, auto_psv)) _IC1Interrupt(){
    IFS0bits.IC1IF = 0;
    if(PORTBbits.RB4 == 1){
        //reset both TMR3 and overflowtmr
        TMR3 = 0;
        overflowtmr = 0;
    }
    else{
        finalTime = (TMR3)*625 + overflowtmr*625*65536;
        overflowtmr = 0;
        TMR3 = 0;
        uint16_t distance = finalTime/((58)*(10000/10));
        if(distance <= distanceThreshold)
            stopMotion = 1;
        else
            stopMotion = 0;
    }
}

void __attribute__((interrupt, auto_psv)) _T3Interrupt(){
    IFS0bits.T3IF = 0;
    overflowtmr++;
}

void __attribute__((interrupt, auto_psv)) _T1Interrupt(){
    _T1IF = 0;
    T1CONbits.TON = 0;
    TMR1 = 0;
    LATBbits.LATB5 = 0;
}


void sendTrig(){
    LATBbits.LATB5 = 1;
    T1CONbits.TON = 1;
}

void delay_ms(unsigned int ms){
    while(ms-- > 0){
        asm("repeat #15999");
        asm("nop");
    }
}

int main(void) {
    setup();
    while(1){
        sendTrig();
        delay_ms(2000); //delay for 2 seconds before sending another trig signal.
    }
}



It seems as if overflowtmr*625*65536 could overflow a uint32_t pretty easily. And then you proceed to divide by a big number too. You should cancel out some terms so that you are multiplying and dividing by smaller numbers. e.g. multiply by 20480 and divide by 29 is equivalent.

You should keep your business logic out of the interrupt even though that chip has built-in hardware multiplier and divider.  It is better that you set a flag in IC1Interrupt and do the rest in your main by polling that flag.
